# List of available keywords for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

It seems I can't use `SHOW` command in SQL Server like `SHOW COLUMNS FROM...` or `SHOW TABLES`.

Is there somewhere a list of all the commands that are available so I know what I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get Table and Column information**

```
Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
```

**Reserved Words**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql

**Stripped and modified from a validation routine**

```
Declare @Reserved table (Word varchar(100))
Insert Into @Reserved values
('ADD'),('ALL'),('ALTER'),('AND'),('ANY'),('AS'),('ASC'),('AUTHORIZATION'),('BACKUP'),('BEGIN'),('BETWEEN'),('BREAK'),('BROWSE'),('BULK'),('BY'),
('CASCADE'),('CASE'),('CHECK'),('CHECKPOINT'),('CLOSE'),('CLUSTERED'),('COALESCE'),('COLLATE'),('COLUMN'),('COMMIT'),('COMPUTE'),('CONSTRAINT'),
('CONTAINS'),('CONTAINSTABLE'),('CONTINUE'),('CONVERT'),('CREATE'),('CROSS'),('CURRENT'),('CURRENT_DATE'),('CURRENT_TIME'),('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
('CURRENT_USER'),('CURSOR'),('DATABASE'),('DBCC'),('DEALLOCATE'),('DECLARE'),('DEFAULT'),('DELETE'),('DENY'),('DESC'),('DISK'),('DISTINCT'),
('DISTRIBUTED'),('DOUBLE'),('DROP'),('DUMP'),('ELSE'),('END'),('ERRLVL'),('ESCAPE'),('EXCEPT'),('EXEC'),('EXECUTE'),('EXISTS'),('EXIT'),('EXTERNAL'),
('FETCH'),('FILE'),('FILLFACTOR'),('FOR'),('FOREIGN'),('FREETEXT'),('FREETEXTTABLE'),('FROM'),('FULL'),('FUNCTION'),('GOTO'),('GRANT'),('GROUP'),
('HAVING'),('HOLDLOCK'),('IDENTITY'),('IDENTITY_INSERT'),('IDENTITYCOL'),('IF'),('IN'),('INDEX'),('INNER'),('INSERT'),('INTERSECT'),('INTO'),('IS'),
('JOIN'),('KEY'),('KILL'),('LEFT'),('LIKE'),('LINENO'),('LOAD'),('MERGE'),('NATIONAL'),('NOCHECK'),('NONCLUSTERED'),('NOT'),('NULL'),('NULLIF'),
('OF'),('OFF'),('OFFSETS'),('ON'),('OPEN'),('OPENDATASOURCE'),('OPENQUERY'),('OPENROWSET'),('OPENXML'),('OPTION'),('OR'),('ORDER'),('OUTER'),('OVER'),
('PERCENT'),('PIVOT'),('PLAN'),('PRECISION'),('PRIMARY'),('PRINT'),('PROC'),('PROCEDURE'),('PUBLIC'),('RAISERROR'),('READ'),('READTEXT'),('RECONFIGURE'),
('REFERENCES'),('REPLICATION'),('RESTORE'),('RESTRICT'),('RETURN'),('REVERT'),('REVOKE'),('RIGHT'),('ROLLBACK'),('ROWCOUNT'),('ROWGUIDCOL'),('RULE'),
('SAVE'),('SCHEMA'),('SECURITYAUDIT'),('SELECT'),('SEMANTICKEYPHRASETABLE'),('SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE'),('SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE'),('SESSION_USER'),
('SET'),('SETUSER'),('SHUTDOWN'),('SOME'),('STATISTICS'),('SYSTEM_USER'),('TABLE'),('TABLESAMPLE'),('TEXTSIZE'),('THEN'),('TO'),('TOP'),('TRAN'),('TRANSACTION'),
('TRIGGER'),('TRUNCATE'),('TRY_CONVERT'),('TSEQUAL'),('UNION'),('UNIQUE'),('UNPIVOT'),('UPDATE'),('UPDATETEXT'),('USE'),('USER'),('VALUES'),('VARYING'),
('VIEW'),('WAITFOR'),('WHEN'),('WHERE'),('WHILE'),('WITH'),('WITHIN GROUP'),('WRITETEXT')

Select A.* 
 From  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  A
 Join  @Reserved 
   on  Column_Name = Word
```

Answer (score 0):

The ISO standard is to query the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql) for meta-data information. A more concise way is to list table/view columns in SQL Server is `sp_help`:

```
EXEC sp_help 'your-object-name-here';
```

In SSMS, you can highlight the desired object name in a query window and press ALT+F1 to execute `sp_help` for that object. With SQL Operations Studio, ALT-F12 will peek the object definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
```

Hope this helps and is similar for columns. Plus, I haven't seen any such list till now but surely will add in future once I see it.